# Keystonejs Field Conditional pointing to value of Relationship field

Tags: keystonejs

Is there a way in keystonejs to use field conditionals for making a field depend on the value of a relationship field? I use a relationship field as a work around for a multi select field type (as suggested [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/12)), however, I am unable to make another field depend on it? Is that possible anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is there is no such option yet. The dependsOn evaluation is obviously done in evalDependsOn.js. I could tweak that file for checking whether the value array of the multi select field contains the depends on values.

```
if (_.isArray(values[key])) {
    var intersection = _.intersection(matches, values[key])
    return intersection.length > 0
}
```

however that would mean I had to specify ids as values in the dependsOn field option, hmmm...

Comment: I would like to add `foreignKey` support in the relationship field, and then you can specify which key is used in the relationship…